# Swift 4 pass data from NSViewController to NSTabViewController

Tags: swift, macos, nsview, nstabview

I have a NSView controller called LOGIN

I have a NSTabViewController called LISTS and this has two tabs:
playlistLists - associated with the class PlaylistLists,
albums - associated with the class Albums

I need to pass a variable from login to playlistLists and i think something like this should work (its from another post), but this is for ios and I need it for macOS

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let barViewControllers = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
    let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[0] as! FirstViewController
    destinationViewController.test = "Hello TabBar 1"

    // access the second tab bar
    let secondDes = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[1] as! SecondViewController
    secondDes.test = "Hello TabBar 2" }
```

so I change it to this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let barViewControllers = segue.destinationControlles as! NSTabViewController
    let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[0] as! playlistLists
    destinationViewController.test = "Hello TabBar 1"

    // access the second tab bar
    let secondDes = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[1] as! SecondViewController
    secondDes.test = "Hello TabBar 2"  }
```

This line I can't figure out how to change it for macOS:

```
    let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[0] as! playlistListsts
```

or maybe is not the right way to do it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you use `as!` to cast from one type to another, you have to specify a class (or struct) *type*, not a variable or property *name*. So if `playlistsLists` is a *property* of type `PlaylistLists`, then your line needs to be

```
let destinationViewController = barViewControllers.viewControllers?[0] as! PlaylistList
```

Comment: well the problem is that I cant seem to use that line beacuse it says: Value of tyoe NSTabViewController has no member viewControllers, so I think that line should be adapted, PlaylistLists is actually my class